# UImagePicker select image from gallery , how scroll the gallery to the bottom?

Tags: ios

I have UIimagePicker that get the image from the gallery ,
but I noticed that when the app open the  gallery,
the gallery open and start showing the images from the top of the gallery which is the oldest images in the iphone.

My question is how to scroll the gallery to the bottom to show the newest images first as I saw in the **Facebook app** when uploading image from the gallery .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the following code to do that and it works for me :

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker; 
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
```